# Number Range for date input using jQuery Masked Input Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

I have some inputs using for date.
I want to have [masked-input](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) for them.
The question is that how can I manage the range of numbers (Persian date):

> yyyy/mm/dd

The acceptable range:

> [1280-1500]/[1-12]/[1-31]

```
 $('.masked-date-picker').mask("9999/99/99", {
    placeholder: " ",
    autoclear: false
});
```

Edited:
I also tested the script, below, based on [documention](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) about supply our own mask definitions:

```
$('.masked-date-picker').mask("YYYY/MM/DD", {
    definitions: {
        'YYYY': "[1280-1500]",
        'MM': "[1-12]",
        'DD': "[1-31]"
    },
    placeholder: " ",
    autoclear: false
});
```

and it didn't work, too. As it converts all inputs to YYYY/MM/DD exactly!!